# Can I `fwrite` a memory view in Cython?

Tags: cython, fwrite, typed-memory-views

Is it possible to write a numpy array to disk using a c `fwrite` function? From the Cython Memory View Documentation, I understand that "they can handle C arrays" but I do not see explicit examples of such.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
cdef FILE *fptr
fptr = fopen("data.dat", "w")
cdef double[:] array = numpy.array([.5, 1.5, 2.5, -9, 0.0, 5])
fwrite(array, sizeof(double), array.size, fptr)
```

But I get the following compile error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
def write_values(file_path):
    """Tracer code to write values to a C file."""
    cdef FILE *fptr
    fptr = fopen("data.dat", "w")
    cdef double[:] array = numpy.array([.5, 1.5, 2.5, -9, 0.0, 5])
    fwrite(array, sizeof(double), array.size, fptr)
          ^
------------------------------------------------------------

write_with_c.pyx:23:11: Cannot assign type 'double[:]' to 'const void *'
```

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Per the docs](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#pass-data-from-a-c-function-via-pointer), you should be passing the address of the first element (`double*` *should* be convertable to `const void*` without casting), and for enforced correctness, you may want to explicitly declare the memoryview with `cdef double[::1] array`, which enforces a C-contiguous memory view, producing the final lines:

```
cdef double[::1] array = numpy.array([.5, 1.5, 2.5, -9, 0.0, 5])
fwrite(&array[0], sizeof(double), array.size, fptr)
```